# Why is the asp:ImageButton not firing the OnClick event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know why the  OnClick event is not working:

```
<div  class="col-sm-1 pull-left" style="margin-top:20px">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="delete_file" 
                     OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you Sure ?');"  
                     OnClick="delete_file_Click"  
                     CausesValidation="false" 
                     Visible="false" 
                     class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-left" 
                     runat="server" 
                     ImageUrl="~/img/del.png" />
</div>
```

c# code :

```
 protected void delete_file_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        int index = GridView2.SelectedIndex;
        GridView2.DeleteRow(index);

    }
```

Comment: Your image button placed inside any other control like repeater or datalist ?

Comment: How are you clicking a `Visible="false"` ImageButton?

Comment: @Filburt : May be it's visible ="True" from some where else :)

Comment: i change  to visible = true after clicking in the grid view

Comment: I guess you always databind the grid on every postback. Wrap this code in a `if(!IsPostBack){....}`

Comment: the same problem with !IsPostBack

Answer (score 0):

Add `gridView.DataBind()` after you `DeleteRow()`.

Comment: the same problem !

Answer (score 0):

You have visible set to false.  So the image button does not get rendered to the page. It does not really exist.

try set style="display:none;"